# Making GET request with header in PHP fails

Tags: php, http, get, file-get-contents

I have made the same request in Postman and it gives me the correct response, but when i make the same call from my website it crashes.

Im simply trying to make a GET request from PHP with one header, the oauth2 authorization token.

Code (googleLogin.php):

```
<?php

$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json";

$options = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                  "Authorization: Bearer " . $_GET["access_token"] . "\r\n"
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

print_r($file);

?>
```

Error:

```
PHP Warning:  
file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json): 
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
in /home/shawn/public_html/cloud/php/googleLogin.php on line 14
```

I dont know if this error implies (i) The file googleLogin.php on the web server doesnt have correct permissions (i tried 777), (ii) The access token is expired/invalid (it cant be because i tried the same token 2 seconds later successfully with Postman), or (iii) php is formatting my HTTP request incorrectly

Comment: why not use cURL library?

Comment: first off i would use cURL or guzzle.

Comment: I'll give those a try thanks

Comment: "Authorization: Bearer " . $_GET["access_token"] . "\r\n" <<< This line is full of fail. You can't reuse the double quotes in your $_GET variable. Either switch all the others to single quotes or assign $token = $_GET["access_token"]; and then use $token in your options array

Comment: Using cURL instead works, thanks!